# Matlab dynamic fieldnames structure with cell arrays

Tags: matlab, structure

How can i access the following structure path with dynamic fieldnames:

```
var = 'refxtree.CaseDefinition.FlowSheetObjects.MaterialStreamObjects{8}.MaterialStreamObjectParams.Pressure.Value.Text';

fields = textscan(var,'%s','Delimiter','.');
```

`refxtree.(fields{:})` does not work because MaterialStreamObjects contains a cell array of which I want to access the 8th cell and then continue down the structure path.

In the end I want to get and set the fieldvalues.

Comment: `refxtree.(fields{:})` wouldn't work even if there was no cell array in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the appropriate input to `subsref`, possibly using `substruct`. Look at the MATLAB help.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718354/232888) there is a nice example to the [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) and [`substruct`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/substruct.html) functions which could probably easily be improved to do what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an anonymous function to navigate this particular kind of structure of the form `top.field1.field2.field3{item}.field4.field5.field6.field7` (as an aside: is it really necessary to have such a complicated structure?).

```
getField = @(top,fields,item)top.(fields{1}).(fields{2}).(fields{3}){item}.(fields{4}).(fields{5}).(fields{6}).(fields{7})

setField = @(top,fields,item,val)subsasgn(top.(fields{1}).(fields{2}).(fields{3}){item}.(fields{4}).(fields{5}).(fields{6}),struct('type','.','subs',fields{7}),val);
```

You use the functions by calling

```
fieldValue = getField(refxtree,fields,8);
setField(refxtree,fields,8,newFieldValue);
```

Note that `fields` is required to have seven elements. If you want to generalize the above, you will have to dynamically create the above functions

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is easier to just use EVAL:

```
str = 'refxtree.CaseDefinition.FlowSheetObjects.MaterialStreamObjects{8}.MaterialStreamObjectParams.Pressure.Value.Text';

%# get
x = eval(str)

%# set
evalc([str ' = 99']);
```