# Dynamical access to nested fields in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

(How) Can I dynamically access nested fields in Matlab? I was thinking about a test case like this one:

```
a = struct;
a.foo.bar = [];

place = {'foo', 'bar'};

a.(place{:})

% instead of the following, which only works if know in advance
% how many elements 'place' has
a.(place{1}).(place{2})
```

Comment: Do you mean [_using dynamic field references_](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)?

Comment: Yes, but with more than one layer.

Answer (score 6):

One solution I am not very happy with, mainly because it lacks the elegance of the `.( )` dynamical field names syntax, is:

```
getfield(a, place{:})
```

Comment: +1: When you don't know the level of nesting, I'm afraid it's the only choice.

Comment: if you inspect the source of `getfield`, its basically a for-loop iterating as `a = a.(place{i})`. I dont see another way either

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of variation, you can use [`subsref()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html):

```
a.foo.bar = 'hi';
place     = {'foo', 'bar'};

% Build subs for referencing a structure and apply subsref
typesub   = [repmat({'.'},1,numel(place)); place];

subsref(a,substruct(typesub{:}))
ans =
hi
```

Without any doubt, `getfield()` is way more readable and faster if you have to build `typesub` (otherwise speed comparisons are indiscernible for such a basic task).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to [subsref()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) and [substruct()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/substruct.html). This might be especially useful for more complex nested access, such as in the question [Matlab dynamic fieldnames structure with cell arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596575).